# How can I set Pre-load image on image loading from Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

I need to start a spinner before loading an image from the server.

My HTML page contains

```
<img src="/imge/abc1.jpg" />
</br>
<p>This tesst text</p>
<img src="/imge/anyname.jpg" />
</br>
<p>This tesst text</p>
<img src="/imge/any.jpg" />
</br>
<p>This tesst text</p>
<img src="/imge/allname.jpg" />
</br>
<p>This tesst text</p>
```

And I want it to show a spinner whilst image loads, like Facebook.
So I need to replace `<img>` to a spinner image until the real image is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do it by `CSS` Just Write code on your `<head>` tag

```
<style type="text/css">
img {
    min-width:50px; /* if load.gif have 50px width */
    min-height:50px; /* if load.gif have 50px height */
    background: url('load.gif') no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may do the trick

just add background image to `img` tag .so the CSS would be

```
img{
      background:url(your laoding image)
}
```

EDIT: or you can add images using javascript
      steps to follow
      1. first load you default image(your loading image)
      2. load you original image but make sure to to set it's display property to none
      3. then after some time change this display property to block (and make sure to remove your default image)

Answer (score 0):

Use FontAwsone Spinner: http://fontawesome.io/icon/spinner/

Use the **fa-spin** class to get any icon to rotate. Works well with fa-spinner, fa-refresh, and fa-cog.

```
<i id="spin" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
```

then use **beforeSend:** with **setTimeout** in ajax to show the loading spinner before the image appear,
**example:**

```
setTimeout(function(){
            $('#spin').show(); //spin is the id of the spinner in <i> tag
            },2000); // 2000ms: spinner appear for 2 seconds before the image appear
```

then use the **succes:** to show the image